# Disable the tap-and-hold application bar that appears in WP8 phone:WebBrowser control

Tags: webbrowser-control, windows-phone-8, application-bar

The phone:WebBrowser control in Windows Phone 8 has a behavior where if you tap-and-hold a text block in the control, a selection mechanism will be enabled and an ApplicationBar with copy-paste functionality will appear. In my app this ApplicationBar hides a critical part of my content. How can I disable the tap-and-hold copy-paste ApplicationBar in the phone:WebBrowser control in Windows Phone 8?

Thanks!

Here is a screenshot showing what I mean:

[image]